# Linux curl request for SOAP webservice call

Tags: linux, curl

I have a SOAP webservice WSDL and when I make a call with SOAP-UI tool, it works perfectly fine....

Now, Im trying to mimic the same call using LINUX CURL but get a 404 error,

Here is my CURL request

```
curl  -v --header "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
     --header "SOAPAction:""" \
     --form "filename=@soap.csv" \
     --form "data=cid:112871000" \
     -X POST https://webservice.test:443/sotest/FileAttachmentService  \
     -u 3user1 \
     -sL -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\\n"
```

The webservice takes the following items as input -

Webservice paramters : -

1.filename
2.data

Here is a snapshot from the SOAPUI tool,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://webservices.test/services/Attachment/v1.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:attachment>
         <filename>Test.csv</filename>
         <data>cid:138641430598</data>
      </v1:attachment>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried capturing the data traffic with e.g. `ngrep` in the two cases? With a near certainty, some header is missing/badly formatted, and this way you could see which one.

Comment: @Iserni..Thanks...How can I capture the request using ngrep?

Comment: With `tshark`: `tshark -i YOUR_ETH_DEVICE -d tcp.port==80,http -Y 'http.request or http.response'`; with `ngrep`: `ngrep -d YOUR_ETH_DEVICE "GET" port 80`. Remember you will not capture the *whole* of a large packet (you will need the full `wireshark` to analyze that), and of course if you do POST you must change the method verb you're looking for (here I put 'GET').

Comment: it would be useful to see working example.